# can i use google sheet formula bundled as alias?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

my cell data likes below:

[image]

I used the function below to get statistics on this data.

=CONCATENATE("2019-01-01 TOTAL :",countif(B:B,"*2019-01-01*")," | COMPLETE :",countifs(B:B,"*2019-01-01*", E:E, "YES"))

it works well, but i think that formula is uncomfortable a little bit. 
so I would like to organize the uncomfortable formula into one like this **statistics("2019-01-01")**

it returns "2019-01-01 TOTAL :3, | COMPLETE :2"

can i solve it at the formula level without using App Script? It is difficult to imitate **COUNTIFS** with App Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create custom functions like `statistics("2019-01-01")` we should use Google Apps Script.